# Psycopg2 Import Error

Tags: python, utf-8, psycopg2

I am trying to import psycopg2 and it keeps throwing the error:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x83 in position 4: invalid start byte.
```

I downloaded psycopg 2.6.2 from the website and ran:

```
python setup.py build
python setup.py install
```

and both completed successfully with no errors.

I then just launch Python (3.4) and just type:

```
import psycopg2
```

and that's where it fails with the UnicodeDecodeError.  I'm reasonably new to Python and I have searched high and low but no idea how to fix this.

For further information the traceback says it is line 50 of `__init__.py:`

```
from psycopg2._psycopg import BINARY, NUMBER, STRING, DATETIME, ROWID
```

Thanks.

EDIT:

I increasingly think the issue might be because I use Windows.  Is it possible that import uses the locale.getpreferredencoding to try and decode? It's weird that this problem only exists with psycopg2 though and other modules can be imported without problem.

Comment: Is the `python` command that you used to run `setup.py` Python 2 or Python 3?

Comment: Python 3 I'm assuming.  The only version of Python I have installed is Python 3.4.

Comment: I never had a problem installing psycopg2 using pip. 'pip install psycopg2'. Although this is just an alternative, and not a solution to your problem. Also, did you just typed 'python' to start the interpreter or 'python3' or something else?

Comment: I re-installed using pip (although from a local file since I have firewall issues) and the same issue occurs.  My interpreter I just type python.  It is Python 3.4.1 Anaconda 2.1.0